# How to superimpose window on panel bar

Tags: window-manager, wmctrl, fullscreen

Fullscreen mode allows a window to cover the whole screen (hence its name), even over the panel bar. How can this be done for a window without entering the fullscreen mode?

Assuming a panel bar on top of the screen, `wmctrl -r win -b toggle,fullscreen` provides the effect mentioned, but `wmctrl -r win -e g,x,y,w,h` cannot go beyond the working area; actually, it can, with negative values for `y`, but it won't superimpose the panel bar, which is always above.

Comment: Tried `xdotool key ctrl+f` or `xdotool key ctrl+shift+f`? I don't exactly remember what was default key for full screen on my terminal.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I'm not trying to open the window fullscreen, but to place it on top of the panel bar W/O being fullscreen.